# Variable registering empty value although initialized in PHP

Tags: php

I am not posting my entire code, just the parts that should hopefully be sufficient enough for the scope of this problem.

```
<?php

$data = array();
$created_by = isset($_POST['created_by']) ? $_POST['created_by']:null;

// initial validation check for all required values
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] != "POST" || $user_group_id == null || $user_group_id == "" || $name == null || $name == "" || $password == null || $password == "" || $mobile_no == null || $mobile_no == "" || $activ_key == null || $activ_key == ""){
    $code="0";
    $msg = "Invalid parameters!"; 
    $data= array(
        "response_code" => $code,
        "status" => $msg
    );
} else {
    switch ($user_group_id) {
        case '2' :
            case2Owner();
            break;
        case '3':
            case3Security();
            break;
        default:
            $code="0";
            $msg = "Unauthorized user!"; 
            $data = array(
                "response_code" => $code,
                "status" => $msg
            );
            break;
    }
}

// function called in switch case 3
function case3Security() {
    // validation check for 'created_by' field
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] != "POST" || $created_by == null || $created_by == "") {
        $code="0";
        $msg = "Invalid parameters!"; 
        $data= array(
            "response_code" => $code,
            "status" => $msg
        );
    } else {

        # extra code

    }
}

// printing result
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

I am writing a PHP script for user signup. Based on the 'user_group_id' it will call the corresponding function. If successful, the resulting output will be in the form of a json string ($data).

I am able to call the function (case3Security) but I always end up in the if-block and not the else-block (where #extra code is). The reason for this is because 'created_by' is empty. As a result, my output is empty.

Is this a scope issue? How do I overcome this? I am using postman to test and below is a snippet of the input in json format.

```
{
    "user_group_id":"3",
    "name":"Random Security",
    "password":"hfkdjf",
    "mobile_no":"1234567894",
    "activ_key":"N98243F7562987N58VT2847T873NC364N87G3C29N87CRFN874YT3N74TCY23N04978",
    "created_by":"2"
}
```

This is confusing because the initial validation (name, password, mobile, etc.) is successful, which means up to that point 'created_by' is not empty, but by the time it reaches the function, something goes wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: FYI you can use [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) to check if a variable is "" or null

Comment: @IsThisJavascript - just for completeness, `empty` also checks for 0

Comment: Just curious, are you setting your variables in the if statement because right now everything like `$user_group_id` is undefined

Comment: if `$created_by` is always null then you need to check you have the correct post parameter

Comment: Thanks guys I know that it is empty, but the problem is that I don't want it to be empty. How do I solve this problem such that 'created_by' is "3" as input by the user, by the time it reaches the function?

Comment: @IsThisJavascript I am setting all the variables exactly where I have set 'created_by', which is before the if condition.

Comment: What does `print_r($_POST)` give you?

Comment: Scope issue based on what you posted and a description of your problem. You aren't passing anything to the `case3Security` function so the `created_by` variable only exists within that function.

Comment: I wish I could downvote every comment above Dave's. This is a really really simple scope issue, and requires absolutely no debugging, just a better knowledge of the language.

Comment: @user3783243 sorry didn't understand the question, i tried entering that in my code to see what it spits out but there's nothing.

Comment: @Dave Yes that is what I figured, but I'm having trouble fixing it.

Comment: IMSop's answer provided a way to solve your problem. I'd recommend going for the pass the variable option as it is much easier to understand and maintain in the long run.

Comment: @Dave appreciate it, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this a scope issue?

Yes.

You can read about variable scope in PHP here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

In short, every function has its own scope, and cannot see variables outside that scope. That means the variable called `$created_at` inside the function is completely separate from a variable with the same name in global code or any other function.

You either need to import the global variable using `global $created_by`, or pass the variable as a parameter to the function. The second option is the much better one, because global variables lead to code that is hard to read, hard to reuse, and easy to break.

Answer (score 0):

$created_by is a global variable. 
You can add the below line

```
 global $created_by;
```

Function

```
function case3Security() {
global $created_by;
// validation check for 'created_by' field
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] != "POST" || $created_by == null || $created_by == "") {
    $code="0";
    $msg = "Invalid parameters!";
    $data= array(
        "response_code" => $code,
        "status" => $msg
    );
} else {

    # extra code

}
```

}